# How do I set up an odd angled hinge?

Tags: animation

I have a door on an angled wall bent 5.5° in x and the hinge of the door is also on an angle y of 5.5°. I tried using an empty to pivot but mid way of the door opening animation the door goes off its hinge the most @frame 30.

How to make it work?

[image]

Comment: The last keyframe has a wrong value.

Comment: You should rotate the empty using R+Z+Z (twice), to rotate along the local Z axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The door will rotate around it's origin, so first move it's origin to the hinged edge.

- In edit mode select the hinge edge of the door.
- Snap Cursor to selected - <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*->Cursor To Selected*.
- In object mode, set origin to geometry. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>->Origin to 3D Cursor.

Focusing on the door by itself, animate it so that it rotates on it's hinged side.

- Align the hinged side of the door to the global Z-Axis.
- Keyframe the door rotating on the Z-Axis.

Then parent the door to the empty and move the empty so that the doors rotation aligns with the wall.

- Clear the rotation of the empty.
- Align the empty to the bottom corner of the door.
- Parent the door to the empty.
- Move the empty so that the door aligns with the wall.

[image]